# another folder creation on Android

Tags: android, directory

It's been two days now I'm stucked on a veeery common and simple problem I don't seem to be able to solve (while other people are):

**creating a folder on a SD card on Android!!!** YES!!!

I red many many posts here, many tutorials that seems to say the same thing:

- create a string with the external folder path + /yourFolderName
- create a new file passing the path as argument
- call mkdir() (or mkdirs()) on it
- done!

alongside you can check if the SD card is MOUNTED, READABLE, WRITABLE, 
and of course don't forget to put in your Manifest.xml the permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but be careful, it must be set as direct child of the manifest and not of the application!!!

Well nothing of that seems to work for me.

The folder_creation code is inside onCreate() and I'm trying to call a MediaScannerConnection to test if the file exists but it return null on OnScanCompleteListener - but I'm not sure I'm using this in the correct way-.

The application runs fine (launch the default camera activity then returns to the main one), but the folder is not created! (by now I just want to create the folder with nothing inside)

Maybe is an issue related to the package name containing the word "example" included in my package name? (I red something related somewhere...)

What could be wrong? Please give me an hint, advice, something...

I'm building on a Mac 1.7.5 with Eclipse using minSdkVersion = 8 and testing on a HTC Wildfire S with 2.3.5 (sdkVersion = 10). Checking with ES File Manager 1.6.1.6 on a non rooted device

Here's the main part of the code driving me crazy...

I would be very glad to know there's something I can do...
Thank you in advance!

```
myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                + "myFolder";

        File newDirectory = new File(myPath);
        Log.v("judy says", newDirectory.toString());
        newDirectory.mkdir(); // this doesn't work because "no directory" is displayed in the logCat window
        if (!newDirectory.exists()) {
            newDirectory.mkdir(); 
            Log.v("no, no, no", "no directory");
        }
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { newDirectory.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is log trace telling you about the line newDirectory.mkdir() other than your own log output

Comment: I'm not sure this is the only output:

11-07 01:35:46.075: W/KeyCharacterMap(2320): Can't open keycharmap file
11-07 01:35:46.075: W/KeyCharacterMap(2320): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'

Comment: and also... 

 11-07 01:41:15.477: W/KeyCharacterMap(2435): Can't open keycharmap file
11-07 01:41:15.477: W/KeyCharacterMap(2435): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'
11-07 01:41:15.477: I/KeyCharacterMap(2435): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I solved: Simply using "uses permission" instead of "permission", the problem was that I was hard writing it in the manifest.xml, instead of using the graphical interface, this way I could use the built in list to choose a permission...

Really sorry if I bored... 
I hope this could be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

This works, if you want to create a directory "/mnt/sdcard/somedir/newdir"

```
  File temp = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (),
                "somedir" + File.separator + "newdir");
        if (!temp.exists ())
            temp.mkdirs ();
```

Comment: ok, I solved: 
Simply using "uses permission" instead of "permission", the problema was that I was hard writing it in the manifest.xml, instead of using the graphical interface :)